# How to copy the text from the UIwebview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, string, uiwebview

I Have some text in my webview which I loaded from a html page.  Now If i want to select a particular word from the Webview then the selected word should be higlighted.

Can we acheive this type of functionality in the weebview?

Comment: can you accept your previous answers?

Comment: have you resolved your question?

Answer (score 1):

## [Search and highlight text in UIWebView](http://www.icab.de/blog/2010/01/12/search-and-highlight-text-in-uiwebview/)

### SearchWebView.h:

```
@interface UIWebView (SearchWebView)

- (NSInteger)highlightAllOccurencesOfString:(NSString*)str;
- (void)removeAllHighlights;

@end
```

### SearchWebView.m:

```
@implementation UIWebView (SearchWebView)

- (NSInteger)highlightAllOccurencesOfString:(NSString*)str
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SearchWebView" ofType:@"js"];
    NSString *jsCode = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCode];

    NSString *startSearch = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyApp_HighlightAllOccurencesOfString('%@')",str];
    [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:startSearch];

    NSString *result = [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"MyApp_SearchResultCount"];
    return [result integerValue];
}

- (void)removeAllHighlights
{
    [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"MyApp_RemoveAllHighlights()"];
}

@end
```

Comment: Do i have to declare the function in the javascript file?

Comment: Thanks can u please show "SearchWebView.js file what contents should we write.